# Text is not going on a new line

Tags: html, css, text, newline, overlapping

When I try to add text that exceeds the width of my div it doesn't go on a new line but starts the same as the previous text and starts overlapping. Can someone see the issue and explain to me how I can make go to the next line instead?

EDIT: I've located the problem to be within my CSS reset part of my stylesheet. But I can't tell which part creates this problem and how I will be able to solve it. I've included it as my css instead.

[image: Example of how it looks]

```css
    html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

body {
  line-height: 0;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
  display: block;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  background: transparent;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
  background-color: #ff9;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
  background-color: #ff9;
  color: #000;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}

del {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  cursor: help;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}

input, select {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="best-comment-rs">
  <div class="rs-rating">
    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="comment">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris at metus tincidunt, finibus massa a, faucibus arcu. In nec dignissim purus. Etiam auctor ullamcorper velit aliquam aliquam. Sed aliquam sit amet urna in pharetra. Cras orci ante, lobortis
      vitae erat et, efficitur interdum mi.”</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your actual code doesn't produce the issue as you can see so please share all the relevant CSS

Comment: I've included all css for the product page that I'm working on.

Comment: @AliÖztürk But as you can see in the snippet you have no problem in the code that you have provided. Kindly provide all the html close near to the element, if possible it's better if you can provide the entire **row**

Comment: Thanks guys, I've found the source of the problem. Now I just don't really know how to fix it. The problem was inside the CSS reset part of my stylesheet

Comment: `body {
  line-height: 0;
}` remove this

Comment: Remove the `line-height` rule in the `body` - `body { line-height: 0;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `line-height` has been set to `0`.

Remove this:

```
body {
    line-height: 0;
}
```